# How to stretch background-image in html and css styling?

Tags: html, css, web, background-image, background-size

I am new to html and css and is trying to create a personal website for learning purposes.

I am having difficulties with the background image not stretching to fit the screen. Providing the code in the following.

```
body{
    background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg);
    /*background-color: #95afc0;*/
    background-size: cover;

}
```

The image works fine when the window is in full screen. I would like to see if there is any way for me to prevent it from duplicating the images to fit the screen and just crop or stretch to fit. As this would be an issue on mobile device. I've tried the other properties of background-size.

Thank you in advance!

[image]
[image]

Comment: try `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: can you share more code?

Comment: Don't forget to mark this question as answered if any answers did answer it. Also, upvote any questions you found helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

### CSS The object-fit [Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Try the following and see what best suits your needs...

```
.fill {object-fit: fill;}
.contain {object-fit: contain;}
.cover {object-fit: cover;}
.scale-down {object-fit: scale-down;}
.none {object-fit: none;}
```

> All Values of The CSS object-fit Property The object-fit property can
>   have the following values:
>
> - fill - This is default. The replaced content is sized to fill the element's content box. If necessary, the object will be stretched or
>     squished to fit
> - contain - The replaced content is scaled to maintain its aspect ratio while fitting  within the element's content box
> - cover - The replaced content is sized to maintain its aspect ratio while filling the element's entire content box. The object will be
>     clipped to fit
> - none - The replaced content is not resized
> - scale-down - The content is sized as if none or contain were specified (would result in a smaller concrete object size)

[image]

```css
H2 {
font-size:200%; color:#6a78c2; text-align:center; font-family: fantasy; 
}

.myimgs {
border:1px solid #333; background:#ff0653; padding:10px; margin-bottom:20px;
}

.myimg {
width:100%; background-position:center; background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fill {object-fit: fill;}
.cover {object-fit: cover;}
.contain {object-fit: contain;}
.scale-down {object-fit: scale-down;}
.none {object-fit: none;}
```

```html
<H2>FILL</H2>

<div class="myimgs">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/67jSBl0.jpg" alt="you" class="myimg fill" width="1049px" height="693px">
</div>

<H2>COVER</H2>

<div class="myimgs">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/67jSBl0.jpg" alt="you" class="myimg cover" width="1049px" height="693px">
</div>

<H2>CONTAIN</H2>

<div class="myimgs">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/67jSBl0.jpg" alt="you" class="myimg contain" width="1049px" height="693px">
</div>

<H2>SCALE-DOWN</H2>

<div class="myimgs">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/67jSBl0.jpg" alt="you" class="myimg scale-down" width="1049px" height="693px">
</div>

<H2>NONE</H2>

<div class="myimgs">
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/67jSBl0.jpg" alt="you" class="myimg none" width="1049px" height="693px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try not to put the background on your `<body>`, but create a `<div id="background"></div>` with `#background {position: fixed; z-index: 1; background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; height: 100vh; width: 100vw;}` (don't forget to apply a z-index > 1 on your first content layer to make your background a background).

Answer (score 0):

```
background-position: center;
background-size: contain;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

you need to add image background position to center and set repeat to no-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
body{
    background-image: url(backgroundimage.jpg);
    /*background-color: #95afc0;*/
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Cover:  Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges

Answer (score 0):

To prevent duplication of background image, you need to add following css property and value:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

For more about background property follow this link: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background/

Answer (score -1):

You need to add background-position: center ( that refers to both axes X and Y ); 
                background-repeat: no-repeat;