# Adjusting Height of Background Image to DIV in both PC and mobile view

Tags: html, css

Here I am trying to put an background on `main_div`. 
I cannot see the full width of an image.
If I switch to mobile view then background keeps repeating.
I did `background-repeat :none` on both Y and X, it will resize image 
and `first Div, Second Div, third Div` collapse.
Why dont the `div` stack upon one above another. 
Design is too simple for this page, 
But the background and stacking of `DIV` is creating problem`

```css
.main_container {
background : url(https://image.ibb.co/btbU6z/concept_bg.png);
height : 1569px;
width : 1122px;
/* background-size: 100% auto ; */ /*If I use this , background image will appear much smaller in device view with contents of first box, second box and 3rd box , all going out of the main container. 
*/
max-width:100% ;
}


/*Also the background image is not shown full width. See the border yellow at left side, 
It is not shown in right side, so its not showing full 100% too.
```

```html
<div class ="main_container">
   <div class="1stcontainer">First Box </div>
   <div class="2ndcontainer">Second Box</div>
   <div class="3rdcontainer">Third Box</div>


</div>
```

Original Website [Link](http://azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/user_data/concept) Make sure to view in device view too.

Comment: Use `vw` and `vh` or `%` instead of `px`. If background still needs some adjustments then use `media` query.

Comment: @Code_Ninja Just tried `vh ` and `vw`by using, When switching to device mode, Just the fraction of image is shown in background, and `DIV `collapse too

Comment: @AnujJoshi, You want to display full image or only display image on the screen?

Comment: for that you have to use background positioning attributes and set it as `cover`. I think [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) link can help you.

Comment: @user9437856 For PC display, it is perfect, but mobile view is destroyed from BG to DIV . I want perfectly stacked DIV as in PC display in mobile view too, with BG

Comment: @AnujJoshi, might be this code will help https://jsfiddle.net/Narendra2015/trjpgwn4/   It will display in mobile as well

Comment: @Code_Ninja I did try `background-positioning: cover` But it will show the whole Background image in smaller view, and other items of rest of the DIV are below it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stretch background-image in html and css styling?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253060/how-to-stretch-background-image-in-html-and-css-styling)

Comment: @InvariantChange Web view is perfect no changes required. Only concern is when switching to mobile view.

Comment: You can use this to solve it...
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;

Comment: @KunalKhatri Here what happens as soon as i use `background-size : 100% auto ` [Link](https://ibb.co/cVZupK)

Comment: You can use this also, 
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: top center;
    width:100%;

Comment: It somehow tried to work, but it cuts the image portion from left to right.

Answer (score 0):

remove the width of the background and use background-size as shown below.

```css
.main_container {
background : url(https://image.ibb.co/btbU6z/concept_bg.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size:100% auto;
height : 1569px;
max-width:100% ;
}
```

```html
<div class ="main_container">
   <div class="1stcontainer">First Box </div>
   <div class="2ndcontainer">Second Box</div>
   <div class="3rdcontainer">Third Box</div>


</div>
```

Comment: But what when switching to mobile view? Esp on iphone device.

Answer (score -2):

you need to set width:100% and height:100% to image and `background-repeat: no-repeat;`
in your image there is no yellow border in right hand side please check.

```css
.main_container {
  background: url(https://image.ibb.co/btbU6z/concept_bg.png);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="1stcontainer">First Box </div>
  <div class="2ndcontainer">Second Box</div>
  <div class="3rdcontainer">Third Box</div>


</div>
```

Comment: Yes thats what M saying, there is no yellow border in right side, but there is in left side. Its part of image. I did set `width :100%` But no improve. + But concern is not only about the width.

Comment: right. but in image itself there is no border so how can you expect border in right side if there is no border in image???????????????

Comment: I edited the image to remove it just now. Because my main concern is adjusting BG to DIV . Can u once see my original website . It looks good and as required on PC mode, but switch to device mode, in iphone 8 or iphone X , You will fig out my problem